# How to achieve constructor / destructor symmetry, for Java

Tags: java, destructor, dispose, finalizer

Coming from a C++ background, I like to have some sort of "symmetry" in the construction and destruction of objects. For example, the constructor allocates resources, attaches event handlers, and the destructor detaches the event handlers and release the resources, in the reverse order as the constructor.

In C# I usually use the "Dispose" pattern to create that behaviour. I'm not using the destructor because the latter might be called from a random thread (as far as I understood), which could be a problem if the deconstruction of my objects contains UI calls.

How could I mimic this behaviour in Java ? Isn't Java appropriate for doing this ? Does Java favor another approach than this one ? I wouldn't want to use Java in a different way than it was designed to be used.

I've searched on SO, but people say there is no such thing as a destructor (that I already knew), or a Dispose-like method. Is there a way to implement that construction / destruction "symmetry" without having the destruction part called from a random thread by the garbage collector ? Or am I looking at things in the wrong way ?

Comment: "Or am I looking at things in the wrong way ?" -- yes, you are, and you will need to change your mindset to one of a Java programmer, same as you would have to change your mindset to one of a Python programmer when coding Python. They all have vastly different philosophies and ways of solving things. Don't look for C++ solutions to Java code concerns.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Would you put me in the right direction ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, give up your search for a non-existing symmetry. Looking for this would be like looking for Java equivalents for C's malloc and free.

Comment: garbage collector is taking care of destruction part (automated), but you could call programmatic if needed

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels At least the C# has a destructor. Even if I don't know which thread is going to call it, I can at least have a piece of code executed when the object is completely unreferenced. If I created some sort of `close` or `destroy` method in Java that I would have to call manually, I would not know, at the place and moment I'm calling it if the object is still being used elsewhere, while a destructor would garanty that the destruction code is only executed only once the object isn't referenceed anywhere any more. How do you handle that in Java ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you are looking for would be to implement Closeable or AutoCloseable and then use your class in a try-with-resources block (or call .close() yourself in a finally block).  But make sure you're doing so for things that are actually scarce resources that need to be cleaned up as such.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems to be similar to the C# `using` keyword.However putting that everywhere in my code would feel like forcing the language to behave in a different way it was designed.

Comment: @Virus721: don't put it everywhere. This is really only used to clean resources -- Files, Streams, Graphics objects -- not objects themselves or memory used by objects.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental difference here is the fact that you have no control in Java when your objects get collected by the garbage collector. And worse, there isn't even a guarantee that the *finalize()* method gets actually invoked prior the object getting collected.

Thus the real answer is: Java does not offer this level of symmetry!

As the other answer suggests, the closest language feature that enables "some amount of control" is in fact to implement the AutoCloseable interface.